# python-nmap hosts never up

Tags: python, networking, nmap

I've been trying to get python-nmap to take in a list of ip addresses as an input and output a list of the hosts that are up. This, however, results in an empty list.

```
def scan(registered_hosts, port):
    hosts_up = []
    nmScan = nm.scan(' '.join(registered_hosts))
    for host in nm.all_hosts():
        if nm[host]['tcp'][port]['state'] == 'open':
            hosts_up.append({
                'host': host,
                'url': 'http://%s:%s' % (host, str(port)),
                'hostname': nm[host].hostname()
            })
    return hosts_up
```

The function's input is a list of ip's (i.e. `['192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.2']`, and I'm passing it as an argument to the `nm.scan()` function after I've joined it with a space. I know at least one of the listed addresses is up, but the command returns an empty list. Any idea on what's going on here?

Comment: Are you sure you are just checking if a host is up or not? NMap is a _port scanner_, although you could use it as a online host checker, it is not the ideal use case. Just to a regular up check a `ping` could be more effective.

Comment: Laterali I'm going to use it to check open ports, but I needed to check if a host is up before going nm[host]['tcp'] since if a host isn't up the tcp key won't be on the host object

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code:

- You don't create a nmap object;
- The scan() does not seems to support multiple ips using this format, although I might be wrong [(scan source code)](https://bitbucket.org/xael/python-nmap/src/401642a51919e67d2cd9dd0e6ac1ee45f25b1307/nmap/nmap.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#nmap.py-194);

Therefore, the fixed code should be:

```
def scan(registered_hosts, port):
    hosts_up = []
    nm = nmap.PortScanner()
    for host in registered_hosts:
        scan_result = nm.scan(hosts=host, ports=port)
        if scan_result['scan'].get(host, {}).get('tcp', {}).get(int(port), {}).get('state', '') == 'open':
            hosts_up.append({
                'host': host,
                'url': 'http://%s:%s' % (host, str(port)),
                'hostname': nm[host].hostname()
            })
    return hosts_up
```

Sadly, this lib seems to be completely synchronous for multiple ips if ain't on a sequence. Therefore if you are looking for an async solution, you should build one yourself :(

*Please take the code with a grain of salt: It wasn't tested.*

Comment: I thought this would work, but the ip is still not in the nm.all_hosts() lists, so even if I try accessing it with nm[host] it throws a KeyError

Comment: Fixed the errors @Corrado. It had a `scan` before the host index, also added several safety checks. - Also tested it myself.